# foreman says "unexpected EOF" in one of the SAME node app in 2 different places

Tags: node.js, heroku, eof, foreman, heroku-toolbelt

i have a sample node.js app in `directoryA`. Then i did `foreman start` in that directory and it worked fine.

afterwords i copied that app into a new location and tried doing `foreman start` from there, it didn't work... here is what i did:

```
$ ########## foreman works fine in directoryA ##########
$ pwd
you/cant/see/me/directoryA
$ foreman start
22:28:30 web.1  | started with pid 80332
22:28:30 web.1  | Listening on 5000
^C

$ ########## copy the same node app from directoryA to directoryB ##########
$ cd ..
$ cp -r ./directoryA ./directoryB
$ cd directoryB

$ ########## foreman doesn't work in directoryB ##########
$ pwd
you/cant/see/me/directoryB
$ foreman start
22:27:28 web.1  | started with pid 80323
22:27:28 web.1  | sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
22:27:28 web.1  | sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
22:27:28 web.1  | exited with code 2
22:27:28 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

it's the same damn app... it's a simple helloworld express.js app as showed in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Show your file web.1 in the directory B.

Comment: There is no web.1 file in my app (unless there is any file inside node_modules)... I copied all contents of directoryA to directoryB as it is

Comment: where is the web.1 file? i don't have anything like that in my node app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting the same error.  It turns out my path included the file Alex's Projects .  Foreman choke and died on the apostrophe in Alex's.  I renamed the folder to Alex Projects and it worked AOK.  I found the answer to this here.

https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/315

Comment: There was no apostrophe in any of the folders inside the node project. From inside the node project, I did a `pwd` and there was an apostrophe in one of the directories in the full path.... i removed the apostrophe and it worked perfectly. Thanks bro.