# Foreman says unexpected EOF in web.1 file - but my node app has no web.1 file

Tags: heroku, foreman, heroku-toolbelt

i followed the tutorial at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs to get a node app up and running in heroku

but after running `foreman start`, it says

```
$ foreman start
07:50:11 web.1  | started with pid 3041
07:50:11 web.1  | sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
07:50:11 web.1  | sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
07:50:11 web.1  | exited with code 2
07:50:11 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
$
```

where is this web.1 file coming from ????

i also ran the following:

```
$ foreman check
valid procfile detected (web)
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just answered this question here.
[foreman says "unexpected EOF" in one of the SAME node app in 2 different places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270987/foreman-says-unexpected-eof-in-one-of-the-same-node-app-in-2-different-places)
Essentially, you can't have any apostrophes in your file path.  (You actually have to rename you folders so they don't contain apostrophes.)  It's a bug in foreman.
I'll take doubt credit for answering your double post, though.  :)  I need to get over 50 reputation so I can start making comments!

Comment: thanks bro..... i could identify the 'apostrophe' after doing a `pwd` from command-line.... stupid bug.

Answer (score 0):

It does not say web.1 file exists, it is a message about `web` process, which is read from your Procfile. Your Procfile should be similar to:

`web: node app.js`

Comment: my Procfile contains `web: node web.js`